# Empty object when creating in PHP

Tags: php, oop, kohana, cassandra

I am using Kohana MVC framework. I want to add a module that will work with PHPCassa object (Cassandra NoSQL).

Problem is that when I create the object I have all it's properties and I can interact with it in construct, but when I create it from different place it's returning as empty object.

I'm sure that I am missing something since I'm relatevely new to OOP. Please help me out here.

Module file

```
<?php

// Loading cassandra libraries, tried to load them here, did not help
//require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/connection.php';
//require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/columnfamily.php';

class Cassandra {

    function __construct($columnFamily) {
        // Loading cassandra libraries
        require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/connection.php';
        require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/columnfamily.php';

        $pool = new ConnectionPool('localhost');
        $cf = new ColumnFamily($pool, $columnFamily);

        // print_r($cf); // This will print object with all the proporties that I can use

        return $cf;
    }
```

Class that will load the module and will create empty object

```
<?php

class Controller_Main extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $a = new Cassandra('timeline');
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($a); // This will print out empty Cassandra object
        die();

        //$this->response->body('hello, world!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it wrong way , you are creating two object in constructor , one the  `Cassandra` object and the other is  `ColumnFamily` and obviously the `new Cassandra('timeline');` will return the `Cassandra` object.

Try this way :

```
class Cassandra {

    static function LoadCassandra($columnFamily) {
        // Loading cassandra libraries
        require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/connection.php';
        require 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/columnfamily.php';

        $pool = new ConnectionPool('localhost');
        $cf = new ColumnFamily($pool, $columnFamily);

        return $cf;
    }
```

And use it :

```
class Controller_Main extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $a =  Cassandra::LoadCassandra('timeline');
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($a); // This will print out empty Cassandra object
        die();

        //$this->response->body('hello, world!');
    }

}
```

Comment: you are welcome. Please check the @cilosis's solution also , his way is to go if your wrapper class object i.e. Cassandra `object` is going to manipulate object `ColumnFamily` and `ConnectionPool` internally.Your design will dictate which way to go forward. Use the singleton pattern:http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php if you are going my way

Answer (score 1):

The *ConnectionPool* and *ColumnFamily* are being used only in the constructor so once it completes, they no longer exist. Also, a PHP constructor returns a new instance when called by using **new**, not the `return` value the way you tried. Maybe try something like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/connection.php';
require_once 'application/modules/cassandra/lib/columnfamily.php';

class Cassandra {

    public $pool = null;
    public $cf = null;

    function __construct($columnFamily) {

        $this->pool = new ConnectionPool('localhost');
        $this->cf = new ColumnFamily($this->pool, $columnFamily);

        return $this;

    }
}
```

Try doing that and then a `var_dump()` on **$a** to see the whole Cassandra object or on **$a->cf** to see the ColumnFamily object. Should show you what you need.

Comment: Hmm, using this my object is full, but I can't use any function that is in `$this->cf`. When I try to do `$a->add('1', 'test');` it gives me `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Cassandra::add()`. However inside construct I can use it.

Comment: The Cassandra object must not have the `add()` method. If you meant to do it with the ColumnFamily object, you'd have to call it like this `$cassandra_object->cf->add();`